# create a new column with existing column in linux and output has a different delimiter than input

Tags: bash, awk

A new column will contain an average of both the marks and only those rows will be shown where the average is more than 90 with a delimiter "|".There will be no column heading or column name.

input :

```
Manish#First#Meridian#95#98
Modak#Second#Meridian#83#75
```

output :

```
Manish|First|Meridian|95|98|96.5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be clear in your question. Always mention 3 simple things in your post. 1- clear sample of your input in CODE TAGS using `{}` button. 2- Show expected output in CODE TAGS and 3rd- post your efforts which you have put in order to fix your own problem, kindly do so and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="#";OFS="|"}{$(NF+1)=($(NF-1)+$NF)/2} $(NF)>90' Input_file
```

OR(a bit short version of above `awk`)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="#";OFS="|"}($(NF+1)=($(NF-1)+$NF)/2)>90' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Manish|First|Meridian|95|98|96.5
```

Comment: thnkuu so muchh for ur help

Comment: @RadheAnkit, your welcome. 1 thing  as mentioned in comments too, always use CODE TAGS and put your efforts in your question. This is what we recommend on SO as we all are here to learn and help each other, cheers.